# (wxWidgets, Windows) Program icon works but not in alt+tab or close box

Tags: windows, icons, mingw, wxwidgets

I'm writing a Windows app using WxWidgets.  I've created the .rc file with my icon resource in it, and my program shows up in Explorer with the designated icon.  However, it only shows up with a generic icon in Task switcher (alt+tab) and in the Close menu (the little box at the upper left corner of every window that lets you move, resize, minimize/maximize, etc.).  Am I missing a step, or otherwise doing something wrong here?  I'm cross compiling under Linux using MingW32 in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting the icon? You need to set the icon for the wxFrame. Something like

```
SetIcon(wxICON(aMyIcon));
```

in the wxFrame constructor, where aMyIcon is the name given to the icon in your .rc file.